# 'Binding' a generic repository to an interface

Tags: entity-framework

I am currently following the following tutorial

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

This tutorial discusses how to implement a generic repository and unit of work.

However, it does not appear to explain how to 'bind' a generic repository to an interface.

Can anyone explain how to do this?  I need to 'bind' my generic repositories to either a generic interface or a derived/custom interface.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by 'bind'? Implement?

Comment: Yes, sorry, 'implement' is the correct term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to define the generic interface:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> 
    where TEntity : class
{
}
```

And make your class implement it:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> 
    where TEntity : class
{
}
```